# LUA - Why is end not needed for referencing?

Tags: lua

```
local ply = LocalPlayer()

local frags = ply:Deaths()

print(frags)
```

Why is end not required for code like this? Is it because it only runs one time?

Why does putting end at the end throw an error?

Comment: `end` is for ending blocks of flow control. You don't have any code blocks here.

Answer (score 1):

In Lua you only need an `end` where you started something.

Missing an `end` or having too many both trigger an error.

Just putting a random `end` in your code would not make any sense to the interpeter because it does not know what you're trying to end.

Refer to the [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 9: The Complete Syntax of Lua](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#9) to see which expressions need an end.

> ```
> stat ::=  ‘;’ | 
>        varlist ‘=’ explist | 
>        functioncall | 
>        label | 
>        break | 
>        goto Name | 
>        do block end | 
>        while exp do block end | 
>        repeat block until exp | 
>        if exp then block {elseif exp then block} [else block] end | 
>        for Name ‘=’ exp ‘,’ exp [‘,’ exp] do block end | 
>        for namelist in explist do block end | 
>        function funcname funcbody | 
>        local function Name funcbody | 
>        local namelist [‘=’ explist]
> funcbody ::= ‘(’ [parlist] ‘)’ block end
> ```

You use it to end a do statement, for and while loops, conditional statements and function definitions